# jQuery focusin and append problem when textarea focus

Tags: jquery, focus, textarea, append

I having problem with append() when the textbox is focus the second time.

```
var i = 1;    
$('textarea').live('focusin', function(){               
        $(this).keydown(function(e){
               var code = e.which;
            if(code === 13) { 
                i++;
                $('#linenumbers').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');}
    });
```

This code will append on

tag for    each number, 2,3,4,5 (the first li is    allread added, that why i=1) But when    the user focus out and then focus in    again it add two li foreache keydown,
6 and 7 = first keydown 
8 and 9 = second keydown

third focus it add 3 numbers, and so on..

How can i check that i just add one    li each time you hit enter.

Hope you get the problem!

Edit, the html:

```
<ul id="linenumbers">
</ul>

<textarea></textarea>
```

when i hit the enter but i get a new line in textarea then it should be two li in linenumbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you add *another* `keydown` event handler each time `focusin` fires. Try this:

```
$('textarea').live("keydown", function(e){
    var code = e.which;
    if(code === 13) { 
        var prevIndex = parseInt($('#linenumbers li:last').text());
        $('#linenumbers').append('<li>' + prevIndex++ + '</li>');
    }
});
```

​

Comment: It only add 1, 1, 1, and after 3 enter keydown it ad like 10 li

Comment: @Frozzare, in my initial answer, prevIndex was not incrementing based on the last LI. You might like to try it now. Also, it would be extremely helpful if you provided your HTML.

Comment: i added my html to my question, it any more then that. Yes, your code works but the focus problem is there. when you focus the second time it add 2 li, and so on.

Comment: @Frozzare - I now understand. The problem is that you are adding *another* keydown event hander *each time* the textarea focusin event fires.